# SELECT top 35 Lat Lan records with reference to a particular Lat Lan from MS SQL Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I am working with a 'NearBy Properties' Module in C#,Asp.net,.net ver 2.0 and MSSQL 2005.My requirement is like ,

I pass a specific `Lat` and `Lan` value to DB,It should fetch me 35 nearest properties by comparing the passed `Lat` `Lan` with the `Lat` `Lan` values already saved in DB.Can this be done in the SQL part itself ?

I can do this in `Asp.net` part by

1. looping through all the rows in a DataTable,then
2. Creating an extra field called 'Miles' in DataTable and inserting Km values in to
   it,like this

   ```
   public decimal calcDistance(decimal latA, decimal longA, decimal latB, decimal longB)
   {
           double theDistance = (Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(latA)) *
           Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(latB)) +
           Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(latA)) *
           Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(latB)) *
           Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(longA - longB)));

   return Convert.ToDecimal((RadiansToDegrees(Math.Acos(theDistance)))) * 69.09M * 1.6093M;
   }
   ```
3. Then Sorting the DataTable with 'Miles' field,and fetching top 35 rows from DataTable.

The **Problem** is,

I have to fetch all the DB rows in to asp part and then do a for loop and then do a sort,this takes up lot of time and resources,Is there any way I can execute this in the SQL part itself ?

**SOLUTION**

I tweaked @Bacon Bits answer below as

```
SELECT PM.Id AS PropertyId,PM.Address,PM.PropertyImage,  ROUND((DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS('9.98')) * SIN(RADIANS(PM.Latitude)) + COS(RADIANS('9.98')) * COS(RADIANS(PM.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(76.27999999999997 - PM.Longitude)))) * 69.09 * 1.6093),0) AS Miles 
FROM Tbl_PropertyMaster PM 
INNER JOIN dbo.Tbl_PropertyApproval AS PA  
ON PA.PropertyId = PM.Id 
WHERE PM.IsDeleted='False' AND PM.Enabled='True' and PA.Action='Approved' AND ROUND((DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS('9.98')) * SIN(RADIANS(PM.Latitude)) + COS(RADIANS('9.98')) * COS(RADIANS(PM.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(76.27999999999997 - PM.Longitude)))) * 69.09 * 1.6093),0) < 1000 
ORDER BY Miles DESC
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548940?

Comment: [SQL Server supports trig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191457.aspx) so it should be possible... You can even precompute most of the trig results if you're happy to sacrifice space for speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following user defined function, which is a conversion of the function you supplied to TSQL.  This should be as accurate as SQL Server can be.  The queries should work on SQL Server 2005 and later.  Note that you should probably evaluate the product of the two static values.  I'm just lazy.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.calcDistance (
    @latA AS NUMERIC(38, 35),
    @longA AS NUMERIC(38, 35),
    @latB AS NUMERIC(38, 35),
    @longB AS NUMERIC(38, 35)
    )
RETURNS NUMERIC(38, 35)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(@latA)) * SIN(RADIANS(@latB)) + COS(RADIANS(@latA)) * COS(RADIANS(@latB)) * COS(RADIANS(@longA - @longB)))) * 69.09 * 1.6093)
END
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c4616/1).  My example uses the location in your test and the Wikipedia coordinates of Mangalore.

Comment: I tried this SELECT Id,Address,(DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(8.4874949) * SIN(RADIANS(Latitude)) + COS(RADIANS(8.4874949)) * COS(RADIANS(Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(76.948623 - Longitude))))) * 69.09 * 1.6093) AS distanta 
FROM Tbl_PropertyMaster 
ORDER BY distanta ASC,   Gives distance with only decimal changes,I dont think that is right

Comment: It may be a parenthetical or order of operations problem, but as I said I was converting your function. The main point is that the math functions are available.

Comment: yes, there is a paranthetical issue at the first sin function. It should be ..SIN(RADIANS(@latA))..

Comment: but some rows are returning a value '9.49281351085778E-05' and other rows are returning correctly and are sorted correctly,but these rows are not taking part in sort and are listed on top of result set.Why is it so @BaconBits ?

Comment: 9.49...E-05 is 0.0000949.....  Assuming the function result is in km, that's, what, about 9.5 cm?  Make sure to round the result to the precision of the input values.  If you enter, for example, 45.98 that's only four significant digits.  Remember that pi is irrational, so you're likely to get as many digits returned as the numeric field has because you're converting to degrees and radians.  Are you trying to find the distance between the same point?  What values aren't working for you?

Comment: Ok it worked,regarding 9.49...E-05,i was looking in to very close by locations.I updated the question above with your 'SOLUTION',Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Scalar Function that calculate the distance between given two set of lan-lat parameters (like you did in asp.net side).
Example:

```
SELECT TOP 35 * FROM Table_1 ORDER BY dbo.calcDistance(field_latitude,field_longitude, param_lat,param_long) DESC;
```

I dont know how to calculate the distance from given two set of lang,lat. It is up to you write the function implementation. You can use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177516.aspx)