# Distance between two latitude, longitude points in miles using standard SQL without trigonometry

Tags: sql

How do I calculate distance between two latitude, longitude points in miles using standard SQL without trigonometry?

Comment: have you got an equation?

Comment: Please edit the question with db platform, and show data types

Comment: https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, consider using the native geography data types. It makes it possible to query by distance and such. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stdistance-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I didn't find any standard SQL solution in the linked "duplicated by" answer...

Comment: Is SO not about developing you own solution, and not asking for "can someone solve this for /me"  ?  The link with the duplicate show how to calculate the distance. this can be done in SQL too. (if enough info is provided in this question...)   but you (@jarlh) are right, I should have linked this one:  [SQL Distance Query without Trigonometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548940/sql-distance-query-without-trigonometry)

Comment: @Luuk This is a duplicate, but a sql-specific answer is much more relevant and if it did not exist the one it was marked as a duplicate as is not sufficient in my mind:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026675/calculating-distance-between-two-points-latitude-longitude?rq=1