# Have an upper limit for SUM() function sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm doing a small calculation in the `select` statement of an sql query along the lines of this:

```
SELECT 
   (select sum(weighting) 
     from table1 
     where id = tablemain.id) * 
   (select sum(weighting) 
     from table2 
     where id = tablemain.id) as rating
from 
  tablemain
```

The problem I have is that one of these `SUM` values should have an upper limit of 8,
e.g. if the `SUM` of the weight columns comes to 10 it should only multiply by 8.

Does anybody have any ideas of how this could be done in the `select` statement or if it's even feasible?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the minimum of two values in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947753/), [What's the best way to select the minimum value from multiple columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368351/), [Is there a Max function in SQL Server that takes two values like Math.Max in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124417/).

Comment: Added an alternative that should be faster, still using CASE WHEN THEN but avoiding the two correlated sub-queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try a case statement.  I would even select the values in a CTE to simplify the code, but the principle is the same.

```
SELECT  
   (select CASE WHEN sum(weighting) > 8 THEN 8 ELSE sum(weighting) END 
     from table1  
     where id = tablemain.id) *  
   (select CASE WHEN sum(weighting) > 8 THEN 8 ELSE sum(weighting) END 
     from table2  
     where id = tablemain.id) as rating 
from  
  tablemain
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note: Thanks to Leons for pointing this out, the below does not work, as** `min` **takes one parameter only per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx:**

```
select min(8, sum(weighting)) ...
```

Comment: The MIN function in T-SQL does not take 2 parameters

Comment: Doh! Yep, agree: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx. I'll edit for future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with your query.  Right now it will do 2 correlated subqueries for every row in tablemain. Another way to do it would be to use joins and group by. Test which is faster in your case.

```
SELECT id, 
 (CASE WHEN t1.w > 8 THEN 8 ELSE t1.w END) *
 (CASE WHEN t2.w > 8 THEN 8 ELSE t2.w END) rating
FROM tablemain as t, (select id, sum(weighting) w  from table1 group by id) as t1, (select id, sum(weighting) w from table2 group by id) as t2
WHERE t.id = t1.id and t.id = t2.id
```

Comment: If either of these relationships are 1:many (which is almost certain considering the use of SUM) then this query does *not* provide the same functionality as the OP's example. `main(id)={1}` & `t1(id,w) = {(1,3) (1,6)}` & `t2(id,w) = {(1,4) (1,2) (1,1)}` : SUM(t1.w) should be 9, yours gives 27.  SUM(t2.w) should be 7, yours give 14.  [So, yes, be careful with your queries.]

Comment: you're right, it was a last minute edit where i tried to outsmart myself. corrected.

Comment: @Dems damn, didn't notice that your solution is esencially the same. Have an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to avoid correlated sub-queries without causing massive duplication...

```
SELECT id, 
 (CASE WHEN (t1.weight > 8) THEN 8 ELSE t1.weight END) *
 (CASE WHEN (t2.weight > 8) THEN 8 ELSE t2.weight END)             AS rating
FROM
  tablemain                                                        AS t
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT id, SUM(weighting) AS weight FROM table1 GROUP BY id)    AS t1
    ON t1.id = t.id
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT id, SUM(weighting) AS weight FROM table2 GROUP BY id)    AS t2
    ON t2.id = t.id
```