# An invalid floating point operation occurred

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a problem with an SQL query and i've narrowed it down to the following code

```
SELECT ACOS( (SIN(PI()* 52.9519918465976/180)*SIN(PI()* 52.9519918465976/180))+(COS(PI()*   52.9519918465976/180)*cos(PI()* 52.9519918465976/180)*COS(PI()* -1.14304013581239/180-PI()* -1.14304013581239/180))) AS test
```

I get the following error message 'An invalid floating point operation occurred'

Can abody see what the issue is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried breaking the expression down into it's components?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your result in `ACOS()` is bigger than `1` which can't be.

That is because of floating point inaccuracy. it could be `1.00000001` for instance. Putting it just a little below `1` works like this:

```
SELECT ACOS( 
             (SIN(PI()* 52.9519918465976/180.0)* SIN(PI()* 52.9519918465976/180.0))
             + (COS(PI()* 52.9519918465976/180)*cos(PI()* 52.9519918465976/180.0)*COS(PI()* -1.14304013581239/180.0-PI()* -1.14304013581239/180.0)) 
             - 0.0000001
           )
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using ACOS to calculate distances between geo points.  The subtraction of '- 0.0000001' is enough to skew my results a bit.  So I instead, but used a MIN function (as [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32209528/10239655) by Craig) like this:

```
SELECT ACOS( 
        (SELECT MIN(x) FROM (VALUES (
             (SIN(PI()* 52.9519918465976/180.0)* SIN(PI()* 52.9519918465976/180.0))
             + (COS(PI()* 52.9519918465976/180)*cos(PI()* 52.9519918465976/180.0)*COS(PI()* -1.14304013581239/180.0-PI()* -1.14304013581239/180.0)) 
         ),(1)) AS value(x))
   )
```

This way ACOS of floats between 0 and 1 remain accurately calculated.