# Use something like LEAST in T-SQL on a datetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the minimum of two values in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947753/getting-the-minimum-of-two-values-in-sql)

Okay what I Have a table with two datetime fields and I want to select the rows where the oldest date is equal to some date variable. I saw the LEAST function used somewhere but I can't use this in T-SQL

I need something like this

```
SELECT LEAST(date1, date2) as theDate FROM theTable WHERE theDate = '2012-09-24'
```

but that will work in T-SQL. Also date1 or date2 can sometimes be null so that may be important to know.

Comment: Already answered see this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947753/getting-the-minimum-of-two-values-in-sql

Comment: The Oracle LEAST function will return the least of two *or more* values.  I came here searching for an alternative to Oracle's LEAST, and all I find here is how to get the least of two values.  I'm going to have to look elsewhere for a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such function in T-SQL. Try:

```
SELECT theDate = CASE WHEN date1 < date2 THEN date1 ELSE date2 END FROM ... ;
```

To handle NULLs you may want:

```
SELECT theDate = NULLIF(CASE WHEN date1 < date2 THEN date1 ELSE date2 END, '20301231')
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    date1 = COALESCE(date1, '20301231'), 
    date2 = COALESCE(date2, '20301231')
  FROM ...
) AS x;
```

Also, you can't reference the alias `theDate` in the `WHERE` clause, it doesn't exist yet. You might want to say:

```
WHERE '20120924' IN (date1, date2);
```

Answer (score 7):

The CASE solution others have provided works well for the case (no pun intended) of two values.  For future reference, it becomes a bit unweildy for three or more values and you might then want to do something like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT MIN(mydate) 
        FROM (VALUES(date1),(date2),(date3)) mylist(mydate)
       ) AS theDate
FROM theTable 
WHERE theDate = '2012-09-24'
```

Comment: Interesting, but requires SQL 2008 or higher.  The OP did not specify.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx

Comment: Agreed with @Matt but, the concept is important, not the syntax. If the OP is using a specific legacy version, they should say so. Easy enough to re-write this using union to cater for that.

Comment: Okay, if you need to reference it in the WHERE clause, put the first select in a CTE or a CROSS APPLY.

Comment: `SELECT MIN(dt) 

FROM (VALUES((SELECT max(CreateDate) FROM Customers (NOLOCK))),

            ((SELECT max(CreateDate) FROM LinkedServ.x.dbo.Customers))) dtlist(dt);`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `case` to mimic `least`, and a subquery so you can refer to the `case` result in the `where` clause:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  case 
                when date1 > date2 or date1 is null then date2
                else date1
                end as theDate
        ,       *
        from    TheTable
        )
where   theDate = '2012-09-24'
```

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers are indeed valid, here it is in the form of a UDF, which is closer to what you asked for:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LeastDate] (@d1 datetime, @d2 datetime)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @least datetime

    IF @d1 is null or @d2 is null
        SET @least = null
    ELSE IF @d1 < @d2
        SET @least = @d1
    ELSE
        SET @least = @d2

    RETURN @least
END
```

Usage:

```
SELECT dbo.LeastDate(date1, date2) as theDate
FROM theTable
WHERE dbo.LeastDate(date1, date2) = '2012-09-24'
```

Or you can use a nested select to do it one time only:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT dbo.LeastDate(date1, date2) as theDate FROM theTable
) t
WHERE theDate = '2012-09-24'
```

Note that the choice of calling the function separately in the where clause or using a nested select is the same as it would be for any SQL function, not just this one.

Comment: So you're going to call a multi-statement scalar function twice for every row? Ouch.

Comment: The OP didn't give any mention to the size of the data, but I suppose you are right - as a general purpose function this would be rather slow on large data.  It could be optimized to a table valued udf (http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions) but then you might as well just do it inline anyway since there's so much involved in calling it.