# C styled min/max in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the minimum of two values in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947753/getting-the-minimum-of-two-values-in-sql)

I'm trying to get all values between a range. I'm doing something like this

```
DECLARE @StartSeq INT
set @StartSeq = (select Sequence from MyTbl where ...)

update ... and MyCol between @StartSeq and @StartSeq+@RelativePosition
```

But if RelativePosition is negative it fails because its a smaller amount then startseq. The easiest solution I can think of is duplicate my code and doing an if (RelPos<0) to see if I want to do @StartSeq+@RelativePosition first or second. However that doesn't seem like the best solution. Is there a way i can do it in sql? I tried min(a,b) but it doesnt work in sql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this would do:

```
update ... and ((MyCol between @StartSeq and @StartSeq+@RelativePosition)
             or (MyCol between @StartSeq+@RelativePosition and @StartSeq))
```

alternately:

```
declare @MinSeq int
declare @MaxSeq int

select @MinSeq = min(Seq), @MaxSeq = max(Seq)
from (values (@StartSeq), (@StartSeq+@RelativePosition)) this (Seq)

update ... and MyCol between @MinSeq and @MaxSeq
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` statement in your between, E.g.

```
and MyCol Between CASE When @StartSeq <= @relativePosition Then @Start Else @RelativePosition End
               And CASE When @StartSeq <= @relativePosition Then @RelativePosition Else @Start End
```

it's rather nasty however, you should really try to ensure that the parameters make sense.