# Sort by minimum value of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sorting, min

I use `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

I need to sort a table by the minimal value of two columns.

The table looks like this:

```
ID: integer; 
Date1: datetime; 
Date2: datetime.
```

I want my data to be sorted by minimal of two dates.

What is the simplest way to sort this table that way?

Comment: It is embarrassing that SQL Server does not have a scalar `MIN` function. Please vote: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/767183/t-sql-provide-scalar-min-and-scalar-max

Comment: the connect website is such garbage...you  go there to upvote and it doesn't do anything.  It doesn't upvote, it doesnt tell you an error occurred, it doesnt even tell you if you need to log in, it just uses some sort of update panel / ajax request where the screen kind of loads something but you get nothing out of it.  Its no wonder even logging bugs or feature requests is barely done anymore.  And by the way, who in their right mind closes a feature request because "we have high priority things to take care of now"...ok..but than what happens to that request!?!?!  MS = Slowly falling apart

Comment: You may be interested in many of the q/a on a related question, how to get the minimum of columns.  Here are two examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947753/getting-the-minimum-of-two-values-in-sql http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21542/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-get-the-minimum-of-multiple-columns-on-sql-ser

Comment: @usr: Possibly, but it might not work for this case. To me, it seems reasonable to expect that if such a function existed, it would work similar to the aggregate MIN, i.e. that it would ignore NULLs, unless all the arguments were NULL (or there were no arguments). ORDER BY, on the other hand, treats a NULL as the smallest value, for any data type. Since the OP wants to use the result for sorting, they might be interested in treating the NULL the way it's treated by ORDER BY rather than how it's treated by MIN.

Comment: I'm not realy sure, what do you mean by the 'sorted by minimal of two dates'. Could you give us an example data, witm more than 3 rows.

Comment: @Infinity - Two bounties? How much "attention" do you feel this somewhat mundane question warrants?

Comment: @usr, SQL Server 2022 has LEAST(), see my (updated) answer below.

Answer (score 60):

**NOT NULL columns**. You need to add **[CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)** expression into **[ORDER BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)** clause in following:

```
SELECT Id, Date1, Date2
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY CASE 
           WHEN Date1 < Date2 THEN Date1 
           ELSE Date2 
         END
```

---

**NULLABLE columns**. As *Zohar Peled* wrote in comments if columns are nullable you could use `ISNULL` (but better to use `COALESCE` instead of `ISNULL`, because It's `ANSI SQL standard`) in following:

```
SELECT Id, Date1, Date2
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY CASE 
           WHEN COALESCE(Date1, '1753-01-01') < COALESCE(Date2, '1753-01-01') THEN Date1 
           ELSE Date2 
         END
```

---

You can read about *ANSI* standard dateformat `1753-01-01` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server).

Comment: That's assuming that the date columns are not nullable. if they are, then the correct order by clause would be `CASE WHEN ISNULL(Date1, '01/01/1753') < ISNULL(Date2, '01/01/1753') THEN Date1 ELSE Date2 END`

Comment: Sure, but OP asked for simplest way and didn't noticed about nullable columns, so in this case It's simplest way.

Comment: I agree, but the OP may not be aware of this issue, so it's worth to mention. you've got my vote up anyway, since your answer contains links to the relevant parts of MSDN and therefor is better then the other answer.

Comment: You really should use the ANSI standard dateformat. 1753-01-01

Comment: Why are you editing your answer 100 times? Adding space deleting space adding space deleting space?

Comment: Just tested rollback function in edit. Nothing special.

Comment: Could you please stop with the rollbacks? It's repeatedly "bumping" your answer and could be seen as an abuse of the editing function. It's also generating flags. If this continues, I will have to lock the answer.

Comment: The question linked is not about a *date format* it's about a *date* (the date of Jan 01, 1753).

Comment: There is no impact using case as try simple order by date1,date2 will give the same result. This is not a solution.

Comment: @qazifarhan you are wrong, If you use `ORDER BY date1, date2` It will order first by date1 and if 2 or more values of date1 will have the same date then will order by date2. This question is about: how to order by minimum value of 2 columns. It should check which one is lower date1 or date2 and then order by It.

Comment: I'm afraid, but this solution won't work for the nullable columns in case `Date1` is `NULL` and `Date2` isn't. You take `Date1` as the minimal date when it equals to `NULL`, but it isn't actually true - the minimal date in the row is `Date2`, because another column doesn't contain `datetime` value.

Comment: For this is used `COALESCE` if date1 is null It take `01/01/1753` value.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas No, I meant exactly what you're saying. Why are you taking `01/01/1753`? Why don't you use the maximum `datetime` value? And why do you use the `NULL` value as the date time value? What if we use a date below `01/01/1753`?

Comment: Because default minimum datetime value is `1753-01-01`

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas Even though you use `COALESCE` your solution it messes up the output.

Answer (score 38):

Use a `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY`:

```
 ORDER BY case when date1 < date2 then date1 else date2 end
```

**Edit:**

If *null values* need to be considered, add `coalesce()`:

```
 ORDER BY case when date1 < date2 then date1 else coalesce(date2,date1) end
```

Explanation:

If date1 < date2 then order by date1. (Both dates are non null here.) Works just like before.

Else use `COALESCE()` to order by date2 (when date2 is not null), or date1 (when date2 is null), or by null (if both dates are null.)

**Edit 2:**

If you're using SQL Server 2022 (or later), you can simply use the `LEAST()` function:

```
 ORDER BY LEAST(date1, date2)
```

(SQL Server's `LEAST()` implementation will return the non-null value if the other value is null. ISO/ANSI SQL's `LEAST()` returns null if any of the arguments is null.)

Comment: There is no impact using case as try simple order by date1,date2 will give the same result.

Comment: Select * from Table order by date1, date2 (100% same result)

Comment: @qazifarhan, I'm afraid, you are wrong here. Simple test: table with 3 rows: `2015-01-10, 2015-01-20`; `2015-01-20, 2015-01-11`; `2015-01-15, 2015-01-15`. This is the order that you'll get when you sort by `MIN` of two dates. If you simply order by date1, date2, you'll get different result.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way is using of the [`VALUES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) keyword, like the following:

```
SELECT ID, Date1, Date2
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY (SELECT MIN(v) FROM (VALUES (Date1), (Date2)) AS value(v))
```

This code will work for all the cases, even with **nullable** columns.

**Edit :**

[The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600737/sort-by-minimum-value-of-two-columns/29600775#29600775) with the `COALESCE` keyword is not universal. It has the important restrictions:

- It won't work if the columns are of the `Date` type (if you use the dates before `01/01/1753`)
- It won't work in case one of the columns is `NULL`. It interprets the
  `NULL` value as the minimal `datetime` value. But is it actually
  true? It isn't even `datetime`, it is nothing.
- The `IF` expression will be much more complicated if we use *more than two* columns.

According to the question:

> What is the simplest way to sort this table that way?

The shortest and the simplest solution is the one which described above, because:

- It doesn't take a lot of coding to implement it - simply add an one more line.
- You **don't need to care** about whether the columns are nullable or not. You just use the code and it works.
- You **can extend** the number of columns in your query simply by adding the one after a comma.
- It **works** with the `Date` columns and you don't need to modify the code.

**Edit 2 :**

*Zohar Peled* suggested the following way of order:

> I would order the rows by this rules: first, when both null, second, when date1 is null, third, when date 2 is null, fourth, min(date1, date2)

So, for this case the solution can be reached by using of the same approach, like the following:

```
SELECT ID, Date1, Date2
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN Date1 IS NULL AND Date2 IS NULL THEN 0
     WHEN Date1 IS NULL THEN 1
     WHEN Date2 IS NULL THEN 2
     ELSE 3 END,
(SELECT MIN(v) FROM (VALUES ([Date1]), ([Date2])) AS value(v))
```

The output for this code is below:

[image: The output result for *Zohar's* way of order]

The `COALESCE` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600737/sort-by-minimum-value-of-two-columns/29600775#29600775) **will not** sort the table this way. It *messes up* the rows where at least one cell of the `NULL` value. The output of it is the following:

[image: Weird ORDER BY of <code>COALESCE</code> solution]

Hope this helps and waiting for critics.

Comment: This will not work as expected with nullable columns. The reason is that MIN aggregating function ignores null values. sqlFiddle is currently down, so I can't show you a live example, but you can take the sql [from this link](http://textuploader.com/xngp) and try to run it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, of course it ignores, but is it wrong?

Comment: To my opinion it's wrong because of the fact that by default, ORDER BY clause does **not** ignore null values. If you sort ascending by a nullable column the null values will be on the top of the result set. Unless specified otherwise, the solution should inspire to mimic this behavior. This is the reason I commented about nullable columns in the first place.

Comment: @ZoharPeled OK, why is it wrong to place the rows where **both** columns are `NULL` to the top? If a row has at least **one** column with the *correct* value this value will be used in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: It's not wrong, but it is wrong to place the rows that have one date null after rows that have both dates. When I ran the code I've got [this result](http://textuploader.com/xnuj). As you can see, null dates are on the 5'th and last rows, where they clearly do not belong.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Disagree, the task is `to order by minimal value in a row` which means if we have only **one** value in a row it will be the *minimum*. I don't understand why do you think that between `NULL` and `datetime` the minimal value is `NULL`.

Comment: I've already explained why I think that: [This is the default behavior of ORDER BY clause.](http://textuploader.com/xnum)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I think it is rather business-specific question. But IMHO it is weird to see rows in the beginning in the **chaotic** order where one cell is `NULL`.

Comment: I would order the rows by thess rules:
first, when both null, 
second, when date1 is null, 
third, when date 2 is null,  
fourth, min(date1, date2). But I agree it's business-specific. for all we know the columns in the original question may not even be nullable, and this hole discussion is meaningless to the OP, but I would rather go with the most general solution and I think Stanislovas's answer provides a better solution for nullable columns.

Comment: @ZoharPeled OK, but the `COALESCE` answer does it in the *chaotic order* anyway. Just check it. When `Date1` is `NULL` the case is always `TRUE` - taking the `Date1` value (`NULL`). When `Date2` is `NULL` the case is always `FALSE` - taking the `Date2` value (`NULL`). In all the cases we are taking the `NULL` value.

Comment: Well, it's still Stanislovas's answer, not mine... I don't see a significant reason to post another answer to this question just because of my *personal* opinion. as you wrote and I agreed: this is very business-specific, so my personal opinion might not fit with the OP's expectations.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I wrote a solution specially for your case. Check it up.

Comment: I think you've over complicated the question. [see my answer here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29876323/3094533)
Anyway, the OP wanted the simplest way, not the most efficient nor the most scalable. I still think that a case is the simplest way to do it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled You are right, I made it more efficient.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use `Case statement` in the `Order By` , then this is another approach, just moving the `Case statement` to `Select`

```
SELECT Id, Date1, Date2 FROM 
 (SELECT Id, Date1, Date2
  ,CASE WHEN Date1 < Date2 THEN Date1 ELSE Date2 END as MinDate 
FROM YourTable) as T
ORDER BY MinDate
```

Answer (score 5):

This may be an alternate solution which does not require branching like `CASE WHEN`. This is based on the formula `max(a,b)=1/2(a+b+|a−b|)` as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58792/how-to-calculate-maximum-or-minimum-of-two-numbers-without-using-if). We get the absolute values of a and b using `DATEDIFF` with a reference date (`'1773-01-01'`).

```
ORDER BY (DATEDIFF(d,'17730101' ,isnull(Startdate,enddate)) + DATEDIFF(d,'17730101' ,isnull(EndDate,Startdate)) 
    -  ABS(DATEDIFF(d,isnull(Startdate,enddate),isnull(EndDate,Startdate))))
```

**Test Data**

```
Create Table #DateData(ID int Identity, Name varchar(15),Startdate datetime,EndDate DateTime)
Insert Into #DateData(Name,Startdate,EndDate) values ('myName','2015-04-17 18:48:27','2015-04-18 18:48:27')
Insert Into #DateData(Name,Startdate,EndDate) values ('myName','2015-04-19 18:48:27','2015-04-18 18:48:27')
Insert Into #DateData(Name,Startdate,EndDate) values ('myName','2015-04-20 18:48:27','2015-04-18 18:48:27')
Insert Into #DateData(Name,Startdate,EndDate) values ('myName','2015-04-11 18:48:27','2015-04-22 18:48:27')
Insert Into #DateData(Name,Startdate,EndDate) values ('myName','2015-05-09 18:48:27','2015-04-18 18:48:27')
Insert Into #DateData(Name,Startdate,EndDate) values ('myName','2015-04-17 19:07:38','2015-04-17 18:55:38')
Insert Into #DateData(Name,Startdate,EndDate) values ('myName','2015-04-17 19:07:38','2015-05-12 18:56:29')
```

**Complete Query**

```
select *
from #DateData order by (DATEDIFF(d,'17730101' ,isnull(Startdate,enddate)) + DATEDIFF(d,'17730101' ,isnull(EndDate,Startdate)) 
-  ABS(DATEDIFF(d,isnull(Startdate,enddate),isnull(EndDate,Startdate))))
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer this way to handle nullable columns:

```
SELECT Id, Date1, Date2
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY 
   CASE 
     WHEN Date1 < Date2 OR Date1 IS NULL THEN Date1 
     ELSE Date2 
   END
```

Answer (score 4):

[Code for max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns/23888942#23888942)

I'm using `CROSS APPLY`, I am not sure about the performance, But `CROSS APPLY` often has a better performance in my experience.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (ID INT, Date1 DATETIME, Date2 DATETIME)
INSERT INTO #Test SELECT 1, NULL, '1/1/1';INSERT INTO #Test SELECT 2, NULL, NULL;INSERT INTO #Test SELECT 3, '2/2/2', '3/3/1';INSERT INTO #Test SELECT 4, '3/3/3', '11/1/1'

SELECT t.ID, Date1, Date2, MinDate
FROM #TEST t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(d) MinDate FROM (VALUES (Date1), (Date2)) AS a(d)) md
ORDER BY MinDate

DROP TABLE #Test
```

Answer (score 2):

I think when you want to sort on both fields of `date1` and `date2`, you should have both of them in the `ORDER BY` part, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM aTable
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN date1 < date2 THEN date1 
    ELSE date2 END, 
    CASE WHEN date1 < date2 THEN date2 
    ELSE date1 END
```

Result can be like this:

```
date1      | date2      
-----------+------------
2015-04-25 | 2015-04-21
2015-04-26 | 2015-04-21
2015-04-25 | 2015-04-22
2015-04-22 | 2015-04-26
```

---

To have a prefect result with `Null` values use:

```
SELECT *
FROM aTable
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN date1 IS NULL THEN NULL
        WHEN date1 < date2 THEN date1 
    ELSE date2 END 
    ,CASE 
        WHEN date2 IS NULL THEN date1
        WHEN date1 IS NULL THEN date2
        WHEN date1 < date2 THEN date2 
    ELSE date1 END
```

Results will be like this:

```
date1      | date2      
-----------+------------
NULL       | NULL
NULL       | 2015-04-22
2015-04-26 | NULL
2015-04-25 | 2015-04-21
2015-04-26 | 2015-04-21
2015-04-25 | 2015-04-22
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd shift focus from *how* to do this to *why* you need this - and propose to change the schema instead. The rule of thumb is: if you need to pull stunts to access your data, there is a bad design decision.

As you've seen, this task is very untypical for SQL so, though it's possible, all the proposed methods are painfully slow in comparison to an ordinary `ORDER BY`.

- If you need to do this often then the minimum of the two dates must have some independent physical meaning for your application.

  - Which justifies a separate column (or maybe a column replacing one of the two) - maintained by a trigger or even manually if the meaning is independent enough for the column to possibly be neither in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

I would order the rows by this rules:

1. when both null
2. when date1 is null
3. when date 2 is null
4. min(date1, date2)

To do this a nested case will be simple and efficient (unless the table is very large) [according to this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21542/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-get-the-minimum-of-multiple-columns-on-sql-ser).

```
SELECT ID, Date1, Date2
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY 
CASE 
  WHEN Date1 IS NULL AND Date2 IS NULL THEN 0
  WHEN Date1 IS NULL THEN 1
  WHEN Date2 IS NULL THEN 2
  ELSE 3 END,
CASE 
  WHEN Date1 < Date2 THEN Date1
  ELSE Date2
END
```

Comment: It doesn't work `Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date`

Comment: It did work for me, but I've updated my answer so that it will not be an issue for any sql server version.

Comment: Still, It doesn't work. `Date1 > Date2` is always false in case one of them is `NULL`.

Comment: Cases in `ORDER BY` is not the simplest solution for the question.

Comment: @dyatchenko I really don't know what you want. [Both of the queries work fine on sql server 2012](http://textuploader.com/xnzx), I don't have a way to test them on other versions but I think they should be OK there as well. 
meanwhile, seems that most voters do think that cases in order by **is** the simplest solution to this question, and I happen to be one of them.

Comment: Here is the proof: http://gyazo.com/385ea999676eedee155f9eaa05334899. Try to add more values with empty `Date2`.

Comment: This looks great. both columns null on the top of the list, column1 nulls right after that, column3 nulls after that, and finally, min value of column1 and column 3 (that is not included for some reason in your image). It's just was I was going for, don't see a problem here.

Comment: But the order of dates in the first column? `2023-04-01` -> `2011-04-01` -> `1750-02-01`. Here should be the opposite order. Like this: http://gyazo.com/c8ef6007a8800b70f8dfbd9e776b3608

Comment: I think the mix of your and mine approach for this task is actually the right answer. Thank you for participation! I broke my mind thinking about that:)

Comment: doesn't matter. the OP specifically wrote "I want my data to be sorted by minimal of two dates.". this all boils down to whether or not you should treat null values as smaller then non-null values.

Answer (score 1):

There's an another option. You can calculate the result column by needed logic and cover the select by external one with ordering by your column. In this case the code will be the following:

```
select ID, x.Date1, x.Date2
from
(
    select
        ID,
        Date1,
        Date2, 
        SortColumn = case when Date1 < Date2 then Date1 else Date2 end
    from YourTable
) x
order by x.SortColumn
```

The benefit of this solution is that you can add necessary filtering queries (in the inner select) and still the indexes will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min` function in `order by` clause:

```
select * 
from [table] d
order by ( select min(q.t) from (
           select d.date1 t union select d.date2) q
         )
```

You can also use `case` statement in `order by` clause but as you know the result of comparing (`>` and `<`) any value (null or none null) with null is not `true` even if you have setted `ansi_nulls` to `off`. so for guaranteeing the sort you wanted, you need to handle `null`s, as you know in `case` clause if the result of a `when` is `true` then further `when` statements are not evaluated so you can say:

```
select * from [table]
order by case 
           when date1 is null then date2
           when date2 is null then date1 
           when date1<date2 then date1 -- surely date1 and date2 are not null here
           else date2 
         end
```

Also here are some other solutions if your scenario be different maybe maybe you evaluate the result of comparing multiple columns(or a calculation) inside a separated field and finally order by that calculated field without using any condition inside your order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, Date1, Date2
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY (SELECT TOP(1) v FROM (VALUES (Date1), (Date2)) AS value(v) ORDER BY v)
```

Very similar to the @dyatchenko answer but without NULL issue