# SELECT Maximum/Minimum of 2 or more fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any shortcut function that is the equivalent of:

```
CASE
    WHEN FieldA > FieldB
    THEN FieldA
    WHEN FieldA < FieldB
    THEN FieldB    
END
```

Obviously, this one is not difficult to write, but say you had more comparisons to make, i.e.

```
CASE
    WHEN FieldA > FieldB
    AND FieldA > FieldC
    AND FieldA > FieldD
    THEN FieldA
    WHEN FieldA < FieldB
    AND FieldC < FieldB
    AND FieldD < FieldB
    THEN FieldB
    ...
END
```

it would get very cumbersome. I understand that a UDF could be created to handle this, or you could do something like:

```
SELECT MAX(Field) FROM
(
SELECT FieldA AS Field
FROM Table
UNION ALL
SELECT FieldB AS Field
FROM Table
UNION ALL
SELECT FieldC AS Field
FROM Table
UNION ALL
SELECT FieldD AS Field
FROM Table
)
```

but is there any shortcut in TSQL for this? Out of curiosity, do other DBMS languages have a built-in function like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the minimum of two values in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947753/getting-the-minimum-of-two-values-in-sql)

Comment: You can insert all the fileds on a @ or # temporary table and then pick the maximum or minium values.

Comment: @MrTux I mentioned the answers given in that thread here in the question, I am just looking to see if there is a more efficient way or, as mentioned in an answer below, it could be added to TSQL, especially if it exists in other languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you seem to want is `greatest()` and `least()`.  Most databases provide these very useful functions.  We can lobby Microsoft to add them.

In the meantime, there is a quirky use of `apply` that can solve this problem:

```
select t.*, maxcol
from t cross apply
     (select max(col) as maxcol
      from (values (fieldA), (fieldB), (fieldC)
           ) v(col)
     ) m;
```