# Using the smaller of two values in SQL condition

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a database of videos with a field for both the video width, and height.

I have queries set up to get videos of a specific resolution however it fails to return any videos that are portrait/vertical.

I would like to be able to do something like `WHERE MIN(width, height) == 1080` but to my knowledge, this isn't possible.

Is there anyway I can get my desired effect in SQLite?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the minimum of two values in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947753/getting-the-minimum-of-two-values-in-sql)

Comment: @Eldar I don't know T-SQL and I'm not sure if it's applicable to SQLite.

Comment: Case When is also applicable to SQLite

Comment: Why not just `WHERE height >= 1080 OR width >= 1080`??

Comment: @juergend Because that would match videos at higher resolutions... 1080 was just an example, not the largest nor smallest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite supports multi argument `min` function which behaves like `LEAST` function.

**min(X,Y,...)**

> The multi-argument min() function returns the argument with the
> minimum value. The multi-argument min() function searches its
> arguments from left to right for an argument that defines a collating
> function and uses that collating function for all string comparisons.
> If none of the arguments to min() define a collating function, then
> the BINARY collating function is used. Note that min() is a simple
> function when it has 2 or more arguments but operates as an aggregate
> function if given only a single argument.

So you must be able to use it in the WHERE clause as you have mentioned in the question

Comment: Oh you're right. I tested this before I posted my question but I guess I made an error in the query as it had failed on me so I assumed it didn't work. Well now I feel stupid. Thank you very much for pointing that out for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a CASE expression in your SELECT.

Something like

```
CASE WHEN width>height THEN height ELSE width END = 1000
```

Comment: Works a treat but was just pointed out that `MIN()` actually does work in this case which is simpler to read, write, and understand. Thank you for the answer though!