# Whats the use of semi-colon (;) in OleDbCommand when it doesn't supports multiple Queries

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

I've been wondering if OleDBCommand doesn't supports multiple queries execution then why ";" is used in it ?

Answer (score 1):

The semi-colon is the SQL statement terminator.  A single statement should be terminated as well, although most parsers don't require it.  More [info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710683/when-should-i-use-semicolons-in-sql-server).

Comment: Yes it is a terminator indeed. But I think ";" isn't meant to be used with OleDBCommand, but is supported by the engine?

Comment: Erm, yes.  OleDbCommand generates SQL statements for the engine.