# Should we end the statement in T-SQL with semi-colon?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use semicolons in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710683/when-should-i-use-semicolons-in-sql-server)

When we are writing a SQL script in T-SQL, should we end each statement with a semi-colon? Does semi-colon work like 'GO' keyword? As of now, I see that it doesn't really matter, but I would like to know which is the best practice?

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's good to get into the habit now because CTE/WITH and MERGE need it, as well as some Service broker stuff as mentioned in the other question. Of course, you could use `;WITH cTE AS ...`

C# etc monkeys have been doing it for years.

It won't work with GO because it isn't a keyword. It's a directive for SSMS and other tools to break a larger script into batches.

Comment: As of SQL 2016 the semi-colon will be compulsory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016

Comment: @maurocam: It is not compulsory yet: that link shows the not using semi-colon is deprecated, and it will be compulsory in a later version. There is a huge body of code out there that will fail if this is added without some form of flag (trace flag or compatibility level)