# is it need to put ';' a semicolon in front of a CTE

Tags: sql, t-sql

is it need to put ';' a semicolon in front of a CTE? would any one have that idea?

Thank you for the replays.........

Comment: This is TSQL only -- Oracle terminates every command with a semicolon, so there's no need.  I assume PostgreSQL handles things similar to Oracle...

Comment: When should I use semicolons in SQL Server?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710683/when-should-i-use-semicolons-in-sql-server

Answer (score 4):

*Only* if the previous statement does not end in `;`

I don't personally because I use `;` on the end of my statements.

When I answer here on SO, I do for clarity.

"WITH" itself can be used in many places so the `;` is needed to enable the parser to determine the [WITH context correctly (CTE link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

A contrived example: where is the statement delimiter?

```
ALTER DATABASE foo SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE SELECT * FROM bar

ALTER DATABASE foo SET OFFLINE WITH MYCTE AS (SELECT * FROM bar) SELECT * FROM MYCTE
```

The same applies to [DROP ASSEMBLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177514%28SQL.90%29.aspx) or [EXECUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176069%28SQL.90%29.aspx) or [RECONFIGURE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176069%28SQL.90%29.aspx) or [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)