# Can we use both Insert and Update in the same button operation?

Tags: sql, vb.net, insert-update

I have a Table name as sales and another is balance. I want to use insert command in sales and update for the balance table. What can I do?

```
     cmd.CommandText = " INSERT INTO SALES VALUES('" & ComboBox1.Text & " ' , " & SILVER & " ," & GOLD & ",'" & ComboBox2.Text & "'," & KILO.Text & ", " & TOUCH.Text & " ," & TOTKILO.Text & "," & TextBox3.Text & "," & TextBox8.Text & "," & KGOLD & "," & KSILVER & "," & TextBox9.Text & " ," & TextBox10.Text & "," & TextBox11.Text & "," & TextBox12.Text & " , " & TextBox13.Text & " )"
     Dim NB As Double
    NB = TextBox11.Text
    ST = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString
    cmd.CommandType = " UPDATE BALANCE SET OBBALANCE = " & " " & NB & " " & " WHERE         CUSTOMERNAME =  " & " '" & ST & "'" & " "
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
```

It shows an error as **Conversion from string " UPDATE BALANCE SET OBBALANCE = " to type 'Integer' is not valid**.

Comment: Little Bobby Tables (http://xkcd.com/327/) would be proud. Use parameterized queries instead of using concatenation.

Comment: Command.CommandType is an enum of CommandType

Comment: Not directly related to the question...but [SQL Injection vulnerability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain) is an issue here

Comment: Consider using Option Strict.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a [semi colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710683/when-should-i-use-semicolons-in-sql-server) at the end of the INSERT statement to split them into two separate statements. But your error is that your are setting your CommandType to a string and this is an enumeration: [CommandType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`CommandType` is an enum which tells what a value in `CommandText` is: a query, a table name etc.

You can't put the query text there.

Instead, you should do either of the following (from best to worst):

1. Put both commands into a stored proc on server side and call the stored proc. This would be a better way.
2. Append the `UPDATE` command to the `INSERT` command.
3. Create another instance of `ADO.Command` and run it again in the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can send both to the server using `;`:

```
cmd.CommandText="insert into ...(...) values(...); update ... set ..."
cmd.Connection=con
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This is also how you'd get back the identity value used, you'd append a `;select @@identity` after the `insert`.

The others covered why `CommandType` is the wrong property to touch so I'll leave it at that.