# When should I not use a semicolon?

Tags: t-sql

Or: *What is not a T-SQL statement?*

Except to resolve ambiguity, T-SQL syntax does not require a semicolon to terminate a statement. Despite this, [Itzik Ben-Gan](http://www.sqlmag.com/blog/puzzled-by-t-sql-blog-15/tsql/semicolon-140706) recommends using a semicolon to terminate a T-SQL statement because it makes code cleaner, more readable, easier to maintain, and more portable.

I don't know a precise definition of what a valid T-SQL statement is, so I might be confused here. But as far as I know, a BEGIN...END block is a T-SQL statement, so should be terminated by a semicolon. For example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempTable') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE #TempTable;
END;
```

The code example in Microsoft's [BEGIN...END documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190487.aspx) supports this conjecture:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT FirstName, MiddleName 
    FROM Person.Person WHERE LastName = 'Adams';
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    PRINT N'Rolling back the transaction two times would cause an error.';
END;
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
PRINT N'Rolled back the transaction.';
GO
/*
Rolled back the tranaction.
*/
```

Itzik Ben-Gan contradicts this in the code example of Excercise 1-1 of [T-SQL Fundamentals](http://www.sql.co.il/books/tsqlfund2008/9780735626010_MSSQLServer08T-SQLFundamentals_ch03.pdf):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
USE TSQLFundamentals2008;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Nums', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Nums;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Nums(n INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

DECLARE @i AS INT = 1;
BEGIN TRAN
  WHILE @i <= 100000
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Nums VALUES(@i);
    SET @i = @i + 1;
  END
COMMIT TRAN
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

Microsoft's [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx) document states that the semicolon "will be required in a future version" of T-SQL.

Commenting on Microsoft's intention to require the semicolon in a future version of T-SQL, Itzik notes some exceptions that aren't supposed to be terminated:

> So far it was a requirement to use a semicolon only in specific cases. Now it looks like the plan is to make it a required terminator for all* T-SQL statements in some future version of SQL Server.
>
> (*) Naturally there are cases that aren’t supposed to be terminated with a semicolon; those include (but are not limited to):
>
> - BEGIN
> - BEGIN TRAN
> - IF
> - ELSE
> - WHILE
> - BEGIN TRY
> - END TRY
> - BEGIN CATCH

Itzik seems to be consistent with himself, but Microsoft itself does not follow his recommendations. Compare Microsoft's `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` and Itzik's `BEGIN TRAN` in the previous examples.

In the code I maintain, I have seen even the `BEGIN` keyword terminated by semicolon:

```
IF @HasWidget = 0x1
BEGIN;
  SELECT WidgetID
  FROM tbWidgets;
END;
```

I believe a T-SQL parser may consider the semicolon following the `BEGIN` keyword to terminate an empty statement rather than terminate the `BEGIN` keyword itself; I don't believe that `BEGIN` itself is a valid T-SQL statement.

This conjecture is supported by the fact that SQL Server 2008 successfully parses and executes the following query:

```
SELECT 0;;
```

It's so confusing because there is no widely available specification of the T-SQL language, like the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/) for Java, so nowhere is there a formal definition of a T-SQL statement.

Am I wrong? Does such a specification exist for T-SQL, and is it publicly available?

Otherwise, should just I believe what Itzik says?

Comment: I've just come across this question looking for clarification on one of your exact points - whether semicolons should terminate BEGIN and BEGIN TRAN - but it seems that there is still no clear authority on the matter!

Comment: @AlastairAitchison If you're still interested, I asked Itzik to explain why he thinks BEGIN TRAN should not be terminated by a semicolon in a [comment on his article](http://www.sqlmag.com/content2/topic/semicolon-140706/catpath/tsql/seriespath/puzzled-by-t-sql-blog-15#commentsAnchor).

Comment: You should also be questioning that `IF` shows up in the list. Just because no semicolon shows up in the middle of an `IF` statement doesn’t mean it should be omitted. E.g., the semicolon in `IF 1=1 SELECT 1;` is still part of the `IF` statement…

Comment: At least in SQL Server 2014, `BEGIN TRAN;` and `COMMIT;` require semi-colons.  Using WITH immediately after `BEGIN TRAN` without a semi-colon produces an error.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> T-SQL syntax does not require a semicolon to terminate a statement.

Actually, this is [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx)<sup>1</sup>. I can't remember for sure, but I think you can still get away with not using them in the upcoming SQL Server 2012, but some version after that will likely require a semi-colon for every statement. Using a semi-colon is also technically required by the [ansi standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt). The point is that now is the time to get in the habit of using one for every statement.

As a practical matter, I don't expect them to follow through with this directly. Rather, I expect SQL Server Management Studio and other development tools to first start issuing warnings instead of errors, perhaps for several versions. This will help developers find and fix all the old non-compliant code. But that doesn't lessen the message: semi-colons are coming, and soon.

For a simple heuristic on when *not* to use a semi-colon, think of the code as if it were a procedural language that used curly brackets for blocks, like C/C++. Statements that would be paired with an opening (not closing) curly bracket if written in the procedure language should not get a semi-colon.

<sup>1</sup><sub>It's almost all the way at the bottom of the page</sub>

Comment: +1; I didn't realize that not ending a statement with a semicolon was already deprecated in SQL Server 2008's version of T-SQL.

Comment: And thanks for a link to the copy of ANSI SQL:92 standard. In section 4.22 it defines all the types of ANSI SQL statement. But still I can't find any official document that specifies Microsoft's T-SQL dialect. The MSDN [Transact-SQL Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510741.aspx) is the closest thing I have found.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it gives simple and useful advice: always terminate with a semicolon. One question remains: why does Itzik say that BEGIN TRAN is an exception to this rule? I posed the question directly to him in a [comment on his article](http://www.sqlmag.com/content2/topic/semicolon-140706/catpath/tsql/seriespath/puzzled-by-t-sql-blog-15#commentsAnchor).

Comment: Is this still valid? This MSDN document indicates in future versions it will be required. ;
Transact-SQL statement terminator.Although the semicolon is not required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be required in a future version. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx

Comment: For reference, in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710683/when-should-i-use-semicolons-in-sql-server) there are several comments stating that SQL Sever 2014 has still not enforced the use of semi colons but the use of T-SQL without them is still a deprecated feature to be removed 'at some point' according to MS.

Comment: While good info and links, I don't think this really answers the question. OP desires to use semi-colons where appropriate but wonders which statements shouldn't have them. This answer gives mere anecdotal guidance ("think... procedural") rather than an explicit list.

Answer (score 31):

Summary, based on the OP's original, quoted list.

Yes semi-colon:

- BEGIN TRAN;

No semi-colon:

- BEGIN
- IF
- ELSE
- WHILE
- BEGIN TRY
- END TRY
- BEGIN CATCH

Also, use them after `END` and `END CATCH`.

Details:

`BEGIN TRAN` is a statement and should be terminated with a semi-colon.

Microsoft's documentation notes the optional semi-colon:

```
BEGIN { TRAN | TRANSACTION } 
    [ { transaction_name | @tran_name_variable }
      [ WITH MARK [ 'description' ] ]
    ]
[ ; ]
```

Microsoft's example has semi-colons:

```
BEGIN TRAN T1;
UPDATE table1 ...;
BEGIN TRAN M2 WITH MARK;
UPDATE table2 ...;
SELECT * from table1;
COMMIT TRAN M2;
UPDATE table3 ...;
COMMIT TRAN T1;
```

Both of the above are from:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929(v=sql.90).aspx

They match the current documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929(v=sql.120).aspx

As for `BEGIN...END`, the Microsoft documentation does not provide clear guidance.

The definition has no semi-colon:

```
BEGIN
     { 
    sql_statement | statement_block 
     } 
END
```

However, their example shows a semi-colon after END:

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT FirstName, MiddleName 
    FROM Person.Person WHERE LastName = 'Adams';
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    PRINT N'Rolling back the transaction two times would cause an error.';
END;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190487.aspx

That trailing semi-colon is not consistent with Microsoft's own documentation for `IF` control of flow language construct:

```
IF Boolean_expression 
     { sql_statement | statement_block } 
[ ELSE 
     { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
```

Neither that definition nor their code example shows any semi-colon:

```
DECLARE @compareprice money, @cost money 
EXECUTE Production.uspGetList '%Bikes%', 700, 
    @compareprice OUT, 
    @cost OUTPUT
IF @cost <= @compareprice 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'These products can be purchased for less than 
    $'+RTRIM(CAST(@compareprice AS varchar(20)))+'.'
END
ELSE
    PRINT 'The prices for all products in this category exceed 
    $'+ RTRIM(CAST(@compareprice AS varchar(20)))+'.'
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717(v=sql.110).aspx

However, their `ELSE` documentation, while also not showing any semi-colon in the definition, does show one in the example, after the final `END`.

Definition:

```
IF Boolean_expression { sql_statement | statement_block } 
    [ ELSE { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
```

Example:

```
IF 1 = 1 PRINT 'Boolean_expression is true.'
ELSE PRINT 'Boolean_expression is false.' ;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182587(v=sql.110).aspx

The ANSI standard doesn't resolve the ambiguity because these are non-standard extensions:

> Control-of-flow statements are not covered by the ANSI SQL standard
>   because these are proprietary SQL extensions.  The SQL Server Books
>   Online is sketchy on the subject and many of the examples (as of this
>   writing) are inconsistent and do not always include statement
>   terminators.  Furthermore, control-of-flow statement blocks are
>   confusing due to the many variations, nesting, and optional BEGIN/END
>   specifications.

http://www.dbdelta.com/always-use-semicolon-statement-terminators/

However, the behavior of the server sheds some light. The following is not a syntax error in SQL Server 2005:

```
DECLARE @foo int;
IF @foo IS NULL
BEGIN
    WITH Blah AS
    (
        SELECT
            'a' AS a
    )
    SELECT
        a
    FROM        Blah;
END
```

So the `BEGIN` itself does not require a semi-colon. However, the following does produce a syntax error in SQL Server 2005:

```
DECLARE @foo int;
IF @foo IS NULL
BEGIN
    WITH Blah AS
    (
        SELECT
            'a' AS a
    )
    SELECT
        a
    FROM        Blah;
END
WITH Blah2 AS
(
    SELECT
        'a' AS a
)
SELECT
    a
FROM        Blah2;
```

The above results in this error:

> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 13 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'with'. If this statement is a common table expression or an
>   xmlnamespaces clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a
>   semicolon.

It also throws that error in SQL Server 2008 R2.

It gets even more confusing. Microsoft's documentation for `TRY...CATCH` shows an optional semi-colon after the `END CATCH`, and their examples are consistent with that.

```
BEGIN TRY
     { sql_statement | statement_block }
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     [ { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
END CATCH
[ ; ]
```

However, if you have a CTE immediately after a `BEGIN TRY`, without a semi-colon, it will throw an error.

```
BEGIN TRY
    WITH Blah AS
    (
        SELECT
            'a' AS a
    )
    SELECT
        a
    FROM        Blah;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

In SQL Server 2008 R2, the above batch throws this error:

> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an
>   xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous
>   statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

The error implies that `BEGIN TRY` is a statement (which it isn't), and that a semi-colon "fixes" the issue (which it does). That's right, this works:

```
BEGIN TRY;
    WITH Blah AS
    (
        SELECT
            'a' AS a
    )
    SELECT
        a
    FROM        Blah;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

However, Microsoft says that's not good practice:

> Posted by Microsoft on 12/29/2009 at 12:11 PM I am resolving the
>   corresonding SQL11 bug as "by design". Here is the explanation:
>
> The semicolon between END TRY and BEGIN CATCH should not be allowed,
>   because they are actually not different statements, but parts of the
>   same TRY-CATCH statement. We only allow semicolons when they separate
>   two statements in a sequence.
>
> A word of explanation why then we allow semicolons after BEGIN TRY and
>   BEGIN CATCH. These keywords serve as opening "parentheses" that start
>   an embedded statement sequence. Semicolons after BEGIN TRY/BEGIN CATCH
>   get parsed as part of that embedded sequence, with the first statement
>   in the sequence being empty. While we allow this syntax, I would not
>   recommend it as a good coding practice because it creates a wrong
>   impression of BEGIN TRY/BEGIN CATCH being independent, standalone
>   statements.

The recommended way to handle that situation is with an extra `BEGIN...END` for clarity:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN
        WITH Blah AS
        (
            SELECT
                'a' AS a
        )
        SELECT
            a
        FROM        Blah;
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

However, that `END` before the `END TRY` should probably have a semi-colon. After all, this will throw an error:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN
        WITH Blah AS
        (
            SELECT
                'a' AS a
        )
        SELECT
            a
        FROM        Blah;
    END
    WITH Blah2 AS
    (
        SELECT
            'b' AS b
    )
    SELECT
        b
    FROM        Blah2;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

Maybe always preceding a CTE `WITH` a semi-colon isn't so silly.

Comment: Two years on, but I thought I'd point out that BEGIN is supposed to have a semicolon. If you check out the comments in this link you'll see that SSMS 17 now produces an error if you have a THROW statement after a BEGIN without a semicolon. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql

Comment: According to a later comment on that page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), this seems to have been an error in SSMS, so a semicolon after BEGIN is _not_ required.

Comment: @MobyDX That page still says "The statement before the `THROW` statement must be followed by the semicolon (;) statement terminator." - so my question now is "is `BEGIN` a statement?" and "why is `BEGIN` in `BEGIN TRY` different from in `IF xxx BEGIN`"?

Comment: I don't work much with SQL Server any more, but this question keeps getting votes so I suppose it's still a discussion topic. @Riley, I applaud your detailed answer. Somehow I overlooked it 6 years ago. Have an upvote :-)

Comment: @MobyDX Is that link broken? I see no comments.

Answer (score 4):

The only situation in which I frequently using a semicolon is when using [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) via the `WITH` keyword - and only then because the `WITH` keyword must be preceded by a semicolon otherwise it returns an error.  In those cases, I write

```
;WITH [exp]...
```

i.e. I precede the `WITH` with a semicolon, rather than terminate the previous statement.

Semicolon usage in SQL seems to be very rare; I occasionally see it after a stored procedure or function declaration by that is the exception rather than the rule. Of all the developers I've worked with I don't believe any have really used the semicolon in the way that you described.

Statements like

```
BEGIN;
    SELECT WidgetID
    FROM tbWidgets;    
END;
```

are hard to understand - if `BEGIN;` is considered a statement independent of its corresponding `END;`, why is `SELECT WidgetID` not a valid statement independent of its corresponding `FROM`?

Comment: The statement preceding a common table expression in the batch must be terminated by a semicolon. If the common table expression begins the batch, then writing `;WITH` is unnecessary. In any case, I think this looks ugly and unintuitive.

Comment: `SELECT x`, assuming `x` is a column name, is not a valid statement because there is no `FROM` clause to define a table expression from which to select the column `x`. But the `SELECT` statement does not require a `FROM` clause in the general case: consider `SELECT 0;` and `DECLARE @x INT = 0; SELECT @x;`. In the second example, the scalar variable `@x` can be selected because it is previously defined.

Comment: @IainElder my point was poorly explained and I've now updated; the suggestion was that if a `BEGIN/END` pair of keywords can be separated by a semicolon then why cannot the `SELECT/FROM` keywords be separated as well? I understand the difference but I don't like semicolon after a `BEGIN` - it makes little sense to me.

Comment: I'm with you on semicolons following `BEGIN`. That example was inherited. The loose specification of `BEGIN...END` syntax causes confusion. [`SELECT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) is better specified. You can't select a *column name* without specifying at least one column source in the `FROM` clause. You can select a *variable* or a *constant* without a `FROM` clause: `SELECT @WidgetID;` is syntactically valid. [Rob Farley](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/04/12/select-and-where-but-no-from-clause.aspx) explains it better with examples.

Comment: An interesting question is why shouldn't `FROM tbWidgets;` just select all the columns from tbWidgets? The SQL language designers decided that you have to explicitly say `SELECT * ...`. This is one of the things I like least about SQL.

Comment: @IainElder, since you should be specifying columns instead of using select *  (which is a SQL antipattern)I don't see why this would bother you?

Comment: @HGLEM `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT whateveryoulikeitdoesntmatter FROM tbWidgets WHERE ...)` - sometimes the SELECT clause serves no practical purpose, but we must include it anyway. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but still.  This sequence...

```
If 1=1
BEGIN
    Throw 50000, 'Test Message', 1
END;
```

Will result in a red squiggly from Intellisense, saying "Incorrect syntax near THROW.  Expecting CONVERSATION....."  *until* you put a semicolon after BEGIN. That seems to say that BEGIN needs a semicolon.

This *might* be an error within Intellisense, though.

Followup from 2023:  I think that IS an error from Intellisense, because the code above will actually work without the semicolon after BEGIN.  SSMS version 19.1 (from September 2023) still gives an Intellisense mark on the THROW statement above, if the BEGIN before it doesn't have a semicolon.

I wish that the SQL engine and Intellisense would agree on what's what.  They should talk to each other.  I haven't found how to report issues with Intellisense -- I found a different Intellisense error related to creating a CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE index on a table, and I would like to report it.