# Invalid object name for cte

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, common-table-expression

I am getting the following error when trying to run this cte

> Invalid Object Name 'cte'

error when using the following CTE statement

```
WITH cte (LOC_ID, [Description], LOC_TYPE)
AS
(
    select LOC_ID, DESCR, LOC_TYPE
    FROM [APOLLO].[dbo].[TBL_STATIC_DATA_LOCATIONS_MERLIVE]
    WHERE LOC_TYPE = 'DC'
) 
select * from cte
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Is that the whole error message?

Comment: @FelixPamittan Yes its pointing to both places i am using cte.

Comment: There must be something wrong with the `SELECT` statement itself. Try running the `SELECT` inside the cte.

Comment: Is this part of a larger script? If you add a semi-colon so that `WITH` becomes `;WITH` does that fix the problem?

Comment: @DaveSexton Yes it does, why do i have to include this?

Comment: @DonaldBury Have a look at [this explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938060/common-table-expression-why-semicolon), why you have to use `;WITH`.

Comment: [Check it out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004322/when-should-i-not-use-a-semicolon). `;WITH` is ugly. Using `;` to terminate every T-SQL statement is a good practice even not required by syntax. It makes code consistent, easier to read and maintain. There still be more and more statements requiring ';' in future version. Don't get yourself into trouble just because of semicolon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the definition of a `CTE` requires that the command preceding the `CTE` itself must be terminated by a semicolon ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) documentation, remarks, 6th) so if your code is part of a batch:

```
SELECT a, c, f FROM TABLE; -- <--- mind this semicolon

WITH cte (LOC_ID, [Description], LOC_TYPE)
AS
(
    select LOC_ID, DESCR, LOC_TYPE
    FROM [APOLLO].[dbo].[TBL_STATIC_DATA_LOCATIONS_MERLIVE]
    WHERE LOC_TYPE = 'DC'
) 
select * from cte;
```

the usual trick is to write `;WITH` but the correct way is to terminate the commands with a semicolon.

Comment: I'm still getting this error while having the semicolon in the preceding command or in front of WITH.

Answer (score 1):

Missing semi-colon ';'

```
;WITH cte (LOC_ID, [Description], LOC_TYPE)
AS
(

select LOC_ID,DESCR,LOC_TYPE
FROM [APOLLO].[dbo].[TBL_STATIC_DATA_LOCATIONS_MERLIVE]
WHERE LOC_TYPE = 'DC'

)

SELECT * FROM cte
```