# Meaning of ; in queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

What is the meaning of ; at the end of queries?

For example; what is the difference between:

```
select 1
select 2
```

and

```
select 1;
select 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710683/when-should-i-use-semicolons-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3):

"From a SQLServerCentral.Com article by Ken Powers:

The Semicolon

The semicolon character is a statement terminator. It is a part of the ANSI SQL-92 standard, but was never used within Transact-SQL. Indeed, it was possible to code T-SQL for years without ever encountering a semicolon.

Usage

There are two situations in which you must use the semicolon. The first situation is where you use a Common Table Expression (CTE), and the CTE is not the first statement in the batch. The second is where you issue a Service Broker statement and the Service Broker statement is not the first statement in the batch."

this is from [When should I use semicolons in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710683/when-should-i-use-semicolons-in-sql-server) which might be what you are looking for

which is in turn "straight a cut and paste"

I think this might be stack overflows version of a joke.

edit: ; are also after merge statements

Answer (score 2):

Using the ; is the correct way to end one statement and start another. If you do not use the ; you may get unexpected results

Comment: >>If you do not use the ; you may get unexpected results<< Can you give an example of such 'unexpected results'? Or you mean error when there is no semicolon before CTE or after MERGE?

Comment: The answer provided by Remus covers what I meant, it is always better to include it even if you dont think its absolutely necessary.

Comment: OK. I didn't know that, thank you. I just got used to not using semicolons at my current job, though first time it was weird. Though for two years I haven't met any problems with that.

Answer (score 1):

It is to denote the end of an Sql statement.

Answer (score 1):

Giving a list of situation that are 'required' is always prone to omission. There are other situations besides commont table expression and SSB which the parser cannot handle w/o semicolon terminating the previous statement, like [`THROW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx) or [WITH XMLNAMESPACES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177607.aspx) and the list is bound to grow.

The correct answer is: semicolon terminators are **required** and should always be put whenever writing new code. Period. Omitting them is *tolerated*, but is on the [official deprecation list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx):

> Deprecated feature: Transact-SQL Not ending Transact-SQL statements with a semicolon
>   Replacement: End Transact-SQL statements with a semicolon ( ; ).

Ignoring this deprecation warning is on your own peril.