# Can you form legal statement in MySQL without using semicolon?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I am starting to learn SQL using MySQL and I got my hands on book ["SQL for MySQL Developers: A Comprehensive Tutorial and Reference"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131497359).

Why the author doesn't place semicolons `;` at the end of the statements?

Can you form legal statement in MySQL without using semicolon?

Here is an example pulled right from the book (p.45)
`CREATE DATABASE TENNIS`. Of course, MySQL shell responds by `->`.

Comment: Why do you use more than one question mark????????????

Comment: you need semicolon to put more statements in one line

Comment: even a one line doesn't work I think, at least quering via console i usually forget the semicolon and the query doens't go, but in php yes as far as I can remember

Comment: give an example please? The only situation I can see this is within stored procedures.

Comment: Hmm, this question appears to be related to the *command line interface* and limitations of when it will/will not send a request. The `;` is *not required* on the server for a single command, but command-line clients typically only send a command after a `;` - this makes sense from a CLI where there is no "run command" (e.g. F5) action, aside from "pressing enter", as SQL commands can naturally continue onto multiple lines.

Comment: You might want to read [MySQL - 3.2. Entering Queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/entering-queries.html) and [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/710683/913097).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many flavors and applications of `SQL` require a semi-colon at the end.  A few do not.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710683/when-should-i-use-semicolons-in-sql-server

Comment: I thought the same but that question is about the SQL Server whereas this one is particularly about MySQL so I posted a link to MySQL official documentation instead in the comments.