# SQL Select Statement with nested group by clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables.   I need to select the column name  and a calculated field from Invoices called balance_due.

The result of the query should be the name and their balance due from all of their records combined.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: sqlfiddle could turn out useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or there is another syntax:

```
;With i As
(
   SELECT vendor_id, sum(invoice_total-payment_total) as totalbalance
   FROM invoices
   WHERE payment_total is not null
   GROUP BY vendor_id
)
SELECT Vendors.vendor_name, i.totalbalance
From Vendors LEFT JOIN i ON Vendors.vendor_id = i.vendor_id
```

Comment: This worked well.  Is there any way to exclude rows from the SUM function where payment_total is null?

Comment: @Mike Ebbert: add a where statement to it. See my updated answer

Comment: What's the `;` in the beginning for?

Comment: @lmichelbacher: You can take a look at :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710683/when-should-i-use-semicolons-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT v.vendor_name, i.totalbalance
FROM Vendors as v
     INNER JOIN (
           SELECT vendor_id, sum(invoice_total-payment_total) as totalbalance
           FROM invoices
           GROUP BY vendor_id
     ) as i on i.vendor_id = v.vendor_id
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and elaborate, explaining how this will work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.  It is what I am looking for.  However I get a 00933 error thrown at line 2 (command not properly ended). "FROM vendors as v"  Any suggestions?