# Is it possible to change which SELECT statement is run with a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that I want to perform a different `select` based on the result stored in a local variable.  My use case is simply that, on certain results from a previous query in the stored procedure, I know the last query will return nothing.  But the last query is expensive, and takes a while, so I'd like to short circuit that and return nothing.

Here is a mock-up of the flow I want to achieve, but I get a syntax error from SQL Management Studio

```
DECLARE @myVar int;
SET @myVar = 1;
CASE WHEN @myVar = 0
THEN
    SELECT 0 0
ELSE
    SELECT getDate()
END
```

The error is: `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.`

Comment: why not use an if then else (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182587.aspx)

Comment: what you are doing with with results of this case ? seems like you can come up with one query which uses case for a column and/or inside where and order clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`IF...ELSE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) syntax for control flow:

```
DECLARE @myVar int;
SET @myVar = 1;
IF @myVar = 0
    SELECT 0;
ELSE
    SELECT GETDATE();
```

Answer (score 2):

brother, for CASE function, it can only return single value such as string, in order to execute different query based on certain condition, if else will be the options.

```
DECLARE @myVar INT
SET @myVar = 1
IF @myVar = 0
SELECT '0 0'
ELSE
SELECT GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use IF not CASE if you want to have differnt select statments. IF is a control flow item, case is for picking alternatives from within a select only.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be

```
DECLARE @myVar int;
SET @myVar = 1;
IF @myVar = 0
    SELECT 0;
ELSE
    SELECT getDate();
```

And if you are just learning some syntax elements, you should also start right away to end every statement with a semicolon.
([When should I use semicolons in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710683/when-should-i-use-semicolons-in-sql-server))

Answer (score 0):

Use this format:

```
IF (@myVar = 0)
BEGIN
  SELECT <something>
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT <something else>
END
```