# Can I use the result of a select statement from mysql to compare it with a variable?

Tags: mysql

I have the following code in the my stored procedure:

```
SET cont_email = SELECT email from contacts  WHERE id=in_id;

IF in_customer_email = cust_email then

**do something**
```

So, I was wondering if instead of creating a local variable and storing the result from the SELECT statement I just paste it directly in the if statement like so:

```
IF in_customer_email = (SELECT email from contacts  WHERE id=in_id) then

    **do something**
```

Also, I was wondering how I can use ORs in MySQL.

Can I do this?

```
IF in_customer_email = customer_email OR in_customer_name = customer_name THEN
```

I have seen the use of OR like this:

```
SELECT customer_id, customer_name
FROM customers
WHERE (customer_name = 'Apple' OR customer_name = 'Samsung')
```

but never inside of an if statement, so I wasn't sure.

And lastly, it has been ages since I could use something like if `var1 = var2`, since this is usually used for assigning not to compare, so I was wondering if this correct or I have to use double equal sign like `var1 == var2`.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Yes 2. Yes 3. Single is fine.

Comment: thanks for your answer @kittykittybangbang, I'm not so sure about my first question though. do I need semicolon at the end of the SELECT statement? `IF in_customer_email = (SELECT email from contacts  WHERE id=in_id;) then`

Comment: Negative, ghost rider. Leave that semicolon off.

Comment: gheesh, @kittykittybangbang, write some answer up for lurking point bro

Comment: @Drew there's something scummy about accepting points for yes/no answers... but you talked me into it. ^_^

Comment: But consider how interesting the Answer could be made to sound, like how a used car salesman top of his field sells with Accepted Sincerity that he cares, that it is interesting, that he is genuinely concerned about your well being, and concerns

Comment: @Drew How's THAT for Accepted Sincerity? ;)

Comment: very nice bangbang. I got a chuckle looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/710683/1816093) and [this](https://www.codecademy.com/blog/78-your-guide-to-semicolons-in-javascript) one too. Some people really get into writing a thesis on the topic. I went to Quora.com  hilarious

Comment: @Drew Well, we've got to fill up all the pages of teh Interwebz somehow, right? ... >_<

Comment: see @kittykittybangbang, that was worth the effort. 35 points and counting :>  A few more like that, and no more begging to get those Edits accepted, they are automatic

Comment: @Drew and you actually get points when you edit a post and you don't have to wait that somebody has to approve it?

Comment: no sir @SaulOrtega, it's all for the love of others at that point :>

Comment: so no more points for edits? that's a drawback at that level then :/

Comment: think how absurd it would be tho. Anyone can edit on top of each other. Pts aren't what we are here for.

Comment: Then how do you make points at that level?

Comment: By answering questions like yours :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Variable vs. Nested Statement?

```
IF in_customer_email = (SELECT email from contacts  WHERE id=in_id) then

**do something**
```

This is a perfectly legal query -- no need to declare the variable beforehand.

## ORs in IF Statements?

```
IF in_customer_email = customer_email OR in_customer_name = customer_name THEN
```

This is also perfectly legal (and often quite useful).

## Use = or == to Compare Values?

```
if var1 = var2
```

This is, contrary to what your programmer spidey-sense may indicate, the proper way to compare values in MySQL queries.