# What is the correct syntax of RODBC query in R

Tags: sql, r, ms-access

I'm trying to query an Access database using RODBC in R using the code below:

```
library(RODBC)
channel <- odbcConnectAccess("S:\\mypath\\PhysiPopDONOTTOUCH\\Physiology.mdb")

data <- sqlQuery( channel , paste ("select Endoscopy.*,
Histology.Diagnosis from Endoscopy JOIN PatientData ON
Endoscopy.HospNum_Id=PatientData.HospNum_Id  JOIN Histology ON
Histology.HospNum_Id=PatientData.HospNum_Id WHERE histology.VisitDate
= Endoscopy.VisitDate"))
```

. This is not successful as I get the error:

```
[1] "42000 -3506 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax
error in FROM clause."
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'select Endoscopy.*,
Histology.Diagnosis from Endoscopy JOIN PatientData ON
Endoscopy.HospNum_Id=PatientData.HospNum_Id  JOIN Histology ON
Histology.HospNum_Id=PatientData.HospNum_Id WHERE Histology.VisitDate
= Endoscopy.VisitDate'"
```

The tables `Endoscopy` and `Histology` are each one to many with the `PatientData` table. What am I doing wrong with the syntax?

Comment: I think you don't need the paste, and I find it helps adding 'as.is = TRUE', which prevents weird formatting conversions.
So try:

data <- sqlQuery( channel , "select Endoscopy.*,
Histology.Diagnosis from Endoscopy JOIN PatientData ON
Endoscopy.HospNum_Id=PatientData.HospNum_Id  JOIN Histology ON
Histology.HospNum_Id=PatientData.HospNum_Id WHERE histology.VisitDate
= Endoscopy.VisitDate", as.is = TRUE)

Comment: I tried removing the paste and adding as.is=TRUE both independently and together but I get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried running the SQL query in Access to check that it is valid?
It looks like your SQL query is missing a semi-colon (;) at the end for instance.
Maybe:
data <- sqlQuery( channel , "select Endoscopy.*, Histology.Diagnosis from Endoscopy JOIN PatientData ON Endoscopy.HospNum_Id=PatientData.HospNum_Id JOIN Histology ON Histology.HospNum_Id=PatientData.HospNum_Id WHERE histology.VisitDate = Endoscopy.VisitDate;", as.is = TRUE)

Comment: Aha. Yes I re-designed the query with the Access visual designer and then cut and pasted the SQL into R. It works without the paste and without the as.is

Comment: Good you solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access SQL requires `JOIN` pairings to be enclosed in parentheses. Also, use of `paste()` is to eliminate long whitespaces inside string values that appear when you break lines in R. And consider using table aliases to concisely reference tables. Include a semicolon terminator too (see: [When should I use semicolons in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710683/when-should-i-use-semicolons-in-sql-server)). See below adjustment:

```
data <- sqlQuery(channel , 
                 paste("SELECT e.*, h.Diagnosis",
                       "(FROM PatientData p"
                       "INNER JOIN Endoscopy e p ON e.HospNum_Id = p.HospNum_Id)",
                       "INNER JOIN Histology h ON h.HospNum_Id = p.HospNum_Id",
                       "WHERE h.VisitDate = e.VisitDate;", sep=" "))
```