# SQL query to count occurrence of a value in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is the INPUT Table having student and his/her two interests of learning different subjects.

| Student | Int1 | Int2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DS | Networks |
| 2 | OS | DS |
| 3 | DS | OS |
| 4 | Networks | DB |
| 5 | OS | Networks |
| 6 | DB | DS |
| 7 | Networks | OS |
| 8 | DB | OS |

Need to find domain of interest and number of students interested in it.

Output Should be

| Interest | Total Students |
| --- | --- |
| DS | 4 |
| OS | 5 |
| DB | 3 |
| Networks | 4 |

Comment: Just a small warning, [Int1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-I:~:text=INT%20(R)-,INT1,-(R)), and "Int2" are reserved words in MySQL. Using Reserved words for column names is something which should be avoided 

Answer (score 0):

First I join the 2 result in a temp table and count by the temp table.

```
;with ETA(ref,count1) as 
(select Int1, count(Int1) from [yourtable] group by Int1
union all
select Int2, count(Int2) from [yourtable] group by Int2)
select count1, count(count1) from ETA group by count1
```

Comment: [A query normally consists of an SQL statement followed by a semicolon.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/entering-queries.html#:~:text=A%20query%20normally%20consists%20of%20an%20SQL%20statement%20followed%20by%20a%20semicolon.), why do you start with a semi-colon?

Comment: If u query from management studio u need to include ; for temp table. If you put in the program, u may exclude the ;   Try it yourself

Comment: "management studio" is that not some Microsoft tool so mssql?  And, even in management studio, the semi-colon is not needed.

Comment: probably I am using the earlier version. The query simply won't run without the semicolon. I tested the query before I posted the answer.

Comment: see: [When should I use semicolons in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710683/when-should-i-use-semicolons-in-sql-server), which was asked and answered 13 years ago.

Comment: Exactly Luke. Refer to the first answer. did you realise I am using CTE.  From your answer. "There are two situations in which you must use the semicolon. The first situation is where you use a Common Table Expression (CTE),"

Answer (score 0):

You can query data from the two columns,then using `UNION ALL` to put them together,finally using `GROUP BY` to statistics data

```
SELECT count(c.student) as cnt, c.inte
FROM
(
SELECT `int1` as inte,student FROM course 
union all
SELECT `int2` as inte,student FROM course 
) c
GROUP BY c.inte
ORDER BY c.inte
```

[**DB Fiddle Demo**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hVkRR1LZZcugBuGxbMCNKk/2)

Test result

| cnt | inte |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | DB |
| 4 | DS |
| 4 | Network |
| 5 | OS |