# Convert comma separated values and join with different tables in Microsoft SQL 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

There are three tables and column have comma separated values as shown below: In table 1 there is a single value(TableValue1) and some values needs to get it from table2(Table2Name1 - get values on basis of name in table 2). In table 3 there is a group of sets present in table 2(Table3Name1 - need to fetch values from table 2 on basis of name).

Table 1 :

| ID | Name | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test 1 | Table1Value1,Table2Name1,Table3Name1 |
| 2 | test 2 | Table1Value2,Table2Name2,Table2Name4,Table3Name2 |

Table 2 :

| Name | Values |
| --- | --- |
| Table2Name1 | A,B,C |
| Table2Name2 | D,E,F |
| Table2Name3 | G,H |
| Table2Name4 | I,J,K |

Table 3:

| Name | Values |
| --- | --- |
| Table3Name1 | Table2Name1,Table2Name3 |
| Table3Name2 | Table2Name2,Table2Name3 |

Result, needs to be like below :

| ID | Name | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test 1 | table1value1,A,B,C,G,H |
| 2 | test 2 | Table1Value2,D,E,F,I,J,K,G,H |

```
select * 
from ( select tbl.id,tbl.name,tbl.value,table2.value 
       from (select id,name,value 
             from table1 
             cross apply string_split(data,',')) as tbl 
       left join table2 on tbl.value = table2.name) as A 
       left join(select b.table3name,tb.value,table2.[values]
                 from(select tbl3.table3name,tbl3.value 
                      from(select tbl3.name,tbl3.[values],value
                           from table3 
                           cross apply string_split(tbl3.[values],',')) as tbl3) as tb 
left join table2 on table2.name = tb.value) as B on A.value = B.name
```

but its not showing correct data.

Comment: What did you try? What is working, what is not?

Comment: This seems like an awful way of storing data. You really should consider a massive change in your database design.

Comment: I think this is an awesome new paradigm, key value table name. People have gotten Nobel prize for less

Comment: @Posting, add this code to the question, it's better!

Comment: @siggemannen , updated the query but it's not working as expected.

Comment: @ Yitzhak Khabinsky , updated it but not showing the expected result.

Comment: I formatted the query to make it, a bit more, readable.... 

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on the issue:

```sql
;WITH table1 AS (
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    VALUES  (1, N'test 1', N'Table1Value1,Table2Name1,Table3Name1')
    ,   (2, N'test 2', N'Table1Value2,Table2Name2,Table2Name4,Table3Name2')
) t (ID,Name,[values])
)
, table2 AS (
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    VALUES  (N'Table2Name1', N'A,B,C')
    ,   (N'Table2Name2', N'D,E,F')
    ,   (N'Table2Name3', N'G,H')
    ,   (N'Table2Name4', N'I,J,K')
) t (Name,[Values])
)
,table3 AS (
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    VALUES  (N'Table3Name1', N'Table2Name1,Table2Name3')
    ,   (N'Table3Name2', N'Table2Name2,Table2Name3')
) t (Name,[Values])
)
SELECT  id, name, STRING_AGG(val, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sort, val)
FROM    (
    SELECT  t1.id, t1.name, MIN(sort) AS sort
    ,   z.val
    FROM    table1 t1
    CROSS APPLY string_split(t1.[values], ',') x
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2
        ON  t2.name = x.value
    LEFT JOIN table3 t3
        ON  t3.[name] = x.value
    OUTER APPLY string_split(t3.[values], ',') x2
    LEFT JOIN table2 t22
        ON  t22.name = x2.value
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT  val, sort
        FROM    (
            VALUES  (CASE WHEN t2.name IS NULL AND t3.name IS NULL THEN x.value END, 1)
            ,   (t2.[values], 2)
            ,   (t22.[values],2)
            ) v (val, sort)
        WHERE   v.val IS NOT NULL
        ) z
    GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name, z.val
    ) x
GROUP BY id, name
```

I basically just follow the rabbithole of string splits from various tables.
Finally, i collect the values from table2 together with what's left over from values in table1, do a grouping to remove duplicate and finally STRING_AGG them together to some fort of CSV string.

As others said, this database design ain't good, as Codd et.al. said, one should never combine multiple values into a single column, and definitely don't combine key / value data in the same column.

Comment: Can you please read these two comments?:  [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710683/when-should-i-use-semicolons-in-sql-server#comment60413127_31742373) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710683/when-should-i-use-semicolons-in-sql-server#comment110475624_31742373)

Comment: I read them! And i know it's technically not needed, but i still like to do it to avoid issues in the long run

Comment: So, you are also typing `;SELECT` to avoid issues in the long run ? 

Comment: LOL, no, but if you prepend some other statement in front of with, it usually complains, so it's easier to do it at once and move on with your life

Answer (score 0):

I tried but I am not sure it is not an optimized solution. But it is the exact solution. and more readable query.

My table names:

> table1 (id int, nam varchar(100), val varchar(100))

[image]

> table2 (name varchar(100),val varchar(100))

[image]

> table3(name varchar(100), val varchar(100))

[image]

```
with cte as(select t1.id,t1.name,value as val from my_db.dbo.table1 t1 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(val, ',')),
cte2 as(select t1.id, t1.name, t1.val, case when t2.val is null then t1.val else t2.val end as val1 from cte t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.val=t2.name) ,
cte3 as(select ct2.id,ct2.name ,case when t3.val is null then ct2.val1 else t3.val end as val from cte2 ct2 left join table3 t3 on t3.name = ct2.val),
cte4 as(select id,name,value from cte3 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(val, ',')),
cte5 as(select ct4.id,ct4.name,case when t2.val is null then ct4.value else t2.val end as val from cte4 ct4 left join table2 t2 on ct4.value=t2.name),
cte6 as(select id,name as name,value as val from cte5 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(val, ',') group by id,name,value)
select id as 'ID',name as 'Name',STRING_AGG(val,', ') within group (order by case when len(val)>1 then 0 else 1 end, val) as 'Values' from cte6 group by id,name;
```

[image]