# Sql for Removing Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2019

Hi I have a table where

| Ticket | Subticket | Date | ProductID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-1 | Jan1 | A212 |
| 1 | 1 | Jan1 | A211 |
| 2 | 2 | Jan2 | B1 |
| 3 | 3-1 | Jan2 | A211 |
| 3 | 3 | Jan2 | B1 |

Each Ticket will for sure have same subticket but can have Another Subticket. the tickets are not in sequence

I need to consider only tickets where subticket is different than ticket or Ticket where only one row exists.

In the above example the output has to be

| Ticket | Subticket | Date | ProductID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-1 | Jan1 | A212 |
| 2 | 2 | Jan2 | B1 |
| 3 | 3-1 | Jan2 | A211 |

I used joins but its by filtering data using having statements

But looking for a better code

Comment: Show us your current code attempt.

Comment: "But looking for a better code"  better than what ?

Answer (score 0):

One approach uses exists logic:

```sql
SELECT Ticket, Subticket, Date, ProductID
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE Ticket <> Subticket OR
      NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM yourTable t2
          WHERE t2.Ticket = t1.Ticket AND
                t2.Subticket <> t1.Subticket
      );
```

Comment: I am not sure if it can happen with OP's project, but in case if there is a chance that multiple rows can exist with same `Ticket` & `Subticket` value then this query may return incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

One other way you might do this is with `row_number`

```
select Ticket, Subticket, Date, ProductId
from (
  select * , Row_Number() over (partition by ticket order by Subticket desc) rn
  from t
)t
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Do we *really* need *another* [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group) clone?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below. Using `CTE` called `TicketCount` to get the list of Tickets which are repeated multiple times. LEFT JOIN it with `Tickets` table. And apply WHERE condition to select records with `t.Ticket <> t.Subticket` or records which does not exists in `TicketCount` with condition `tc.Ticket IS NULL`.

```
;WITH TicketCount AS (
    SELECT Ticket
    FROM Tickets
    GROUP BY Ticket
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
)
SELECT t.*
FROM Tickets t
LEFT JOIN TicketCount tc ON tc.Ticket = t.Ticket
WHERE t.Ticket <> t.Subticket OR tc.Ticket IS NULL
```

Comment: [When should I use semicolons in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710683/when-should-i-use-semicolons-in-sql-server)